# Requests Response object KeyError

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the following the following code

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response_dict = response.json()
print(response_dict)
user_name = response_dict['data']['username']
password = response_dict['data']['password']
```

My print returns:

```
{'request_id': 'hidden', 'lease_id': 'hidden', 'renewable': True, 'lease_duration': 3600, 'data': {'password': 'hidden', 'username': 'hidden'}, 'wrap_info': None, 'warnings': None, 'auth': None}
```

I get a key error

```
'data': KeyError
```

What seems to be the mistake here?

Comment: Are you sure there is no list in your response?

Comment: If your `response_dict ` is as you showed, there is no error. They cannot coexist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with my VPC once the code was pushed to a lambda, I did not have permission to move forward with requests sometimes due to race condition.